# TexnicCenter User Interface

Tags: texniccenter

I use TexnicCenter at home and work as well. because I have different sceen sizes, the **Bookmarks** in **Graphical User Interface** has always to be adjusted manually (see picture)[image]

Which I (each time) have to manually arrange to look like [image]

Is there a way to save such configurations?

Comment: Why do you have them **all** _always_ open? They are meant to be opened temporarily. Let the toolbar for mathematical symbols always activated, that’s enough. (That’s why you have the sequence of yellow marked symbols now: These are the switches of the mathematical toolbar. Note also that some symbols are doubled.) **To your question:** I cannot tell you what is happening, because I do not observe this here: The order is preserved after closing and re-opening.

Comment: Same as @Speravir, I have no idea.  Maybe you should try to re-install a fresh copy.